# mount directory to container won't work with podman

Tags: podman

As I have fedora I tried to run the nginx example from their tutorial, i don't get nginx to show any content.

When i run the this container:

```
podman run --name mynginx1 -p 8080:80 -d nginx
```

I get the *Welcome to nginx!* page.

But when i try to run the example with a directory mounted:

```
podman run --name mynginx2 \
  --mount type=bind,source=/home/simon/Dokumente/podman/nginx/content,target=/usr/share/nginx/html \
  -p 9080:80 -d nginx
```

I also get the *Welcome to nginx!* page, but I have an `index.html` file in that source directory.

What is the problem with that container?

Comment: Might be a dumb question but ya never know; are you going to localhost:9080 instead of localhost:8080 when testing the mounted version?

Comment: [podman 4.x does support `--volume`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71497834/6309), including folder bind mount

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes , indeed it's a SElinux issue as @harik , but disabling selinux is not a secure option, rather apply the `Z` flag when mounting the volume, this deals with applying the appropriate labels as mentioned [here](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/3683#issuecomment-517239831) and also [here](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/user-namespaces-selinux-rootless-containers)

```
podman run --name mynginx2 \
  -v /home/simon/Dokumente/podman/nginx/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:Z \
  -p 9080:80 -d nginx
```

Comment: After hours of searching, this worked! Granted, I think the syntax is pretty unintuitive and a bit ugly (I would have never discovered this on my own). Thanks!

Comment: I also have to add `--userns=keep-id` when I do this with either `--volume` or `--mount`

Answer (score 3):

You can run the podman command with the `--privileged` flag to disable host isolation:

```
$ podman run --name mynginx2 --privileged \
  --mount type=bind,source=/home/simon/Dokumente/podman/nginx/content,target=/usr/share/nginx/html \
  -p 9080:80 -d nginx
```

From the `podman` man page:

> --privileged=true|false
>
> Give extended privileges to this container. The default is false.
>
> By default, Podman containers are unprivileged (=false) and cannot,
> for example, modify parts of the operating system. This is because by
> default a container is only allowed limited access to devices. A
> "privileged" container is given the same access to devices as the user
> launching the container.
>
> A privileged container turns off the security features that isolate
> the container from the host. Dropped Capabilities, limited devices,
> read-only mount points, Apparmor/SELinux separation, and Seccomp
> filters are all disabled.
>
> Rootless containers cannot have more privileges than the account that
> launched them.

Comment: I think the answer by @James Dube is better in this case. It achieves the same goal without turning off all the security features.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with a mounted network drive, a pod and or a podman version < 4.0 (iirc all Ubuntu <20.10).

Pass `--group-add keep-groups` when running the container / pod.
I.e `podman run -d -v /mnt/data:/data --group-add keep-groups`

or in case of a pod where container `con2` needs access to `/mnt/data`:

```
buildah bud -f Dockerfile -t doit
podman pod create -n podgroup
podman run -d --pod podgroup --name=con1 localhost/doit
podman run -d -v /mnt/data:/data --group-add keep-groups --pod podgroup --name con2 localhost/doit
```

Here it was not possible to pass `--mount` to `podman pod create`, so none of the presented solutions worked.
Hope this saves the fellow visitor a few hours of time.

Docs: https://docs.podman.io/en/v3.4.2/markdown/podman-run.1.html#configure-keep-supplemental-groups-for-access-to-volume

Answer (score -1):

When we bind volume it loses permission to the path `/usr/share/nginx/html`. It happens because of SELinux enforcement.

mynginx1

```
root@f3fb6ece7eba:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
50x.html  index.html
```

mynginx2

```
root@af0803674402:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

Check the SELinux policy of the host which runs podman.

```
$ getenforce 
Enforcing
```

If it is in `Enforcing` mode change it to `Permissive`.

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
$ getenforce 
Permissive
```

Re-run the mynginx2 container, `exec` and access the contents of `/usr/share/nginx/html`

```
$ podman run --name mynginx2 --mount type=bind,source=/home/tc/q2,target=/usr/share/nginx/html -p 9080:80 -d nginx
7ff2bdfb7ccfc6f90a9bd7957b08e48ea72d7c2303d47d11a412c6c8601976b6
$ podman exec -it mynginx2 bash
root@7ff2bdfb7ccf:/# cd /usr/share/nginx/html/
root@7ff2bdfb7ccf:/usr/share/nginx/html# ls
index.html


$ curl -I -s 127.0.0.1:8080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

$ curl -I 127.0.0.1:9080
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right and secure solution.