# How to mount a volume from a local machine on Podman

Tags: podman

I'm trying to use Podman for local development. My idea is to use a local folder and sync it with the container where I'll be running my application.

I found that the `-v` option that I would use if I was working with Docker works with the server machine, as it says in the documentation `-v Bind mount a volume into the container. Volume src will be on the server machine, not the client`. Because of that, when I use that option the folder is not mounted and I can't find it when I access it using `podman exec -it application bash`

Is there a way I can sort this out?
I want to something equivalent to:

`docker run -v localFolder:/remoteFolder application`

where `localFolder` is a path in my local machine, that will be mapped on `remoteFolder` on the container

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```bash
podman machine stop podman-machine-default
podman machine rm podman-machine-default

podman machine init -v $HOME:$HOME
podman machine start

podman run -ti --rm -v $HOME:$HOME busybox
```

Comment: Why not `init -v ${HOME}:${HOME}` as I did in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71882521/179581 ? Any security implications?

Comment: I think that doesn’t work: you don’t have permission. Not sure it changed. I would love to use this way if podman supports it.

Comment: Works fine for me on macOS. Cannot test for other OS right now so idk

Comment: Just tested and yes it worked. Don't understand why official podman machine init man page says: ```The root filesystem is mounted read-only in the default operating system, so mounts must be created under the /mnt directory. ``` https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-init.1.html Maybe something changed with time. Thank you @Andrei ! I updated the answer.

Comment: A good example to verify this https://medium.com/@butkovic/favoring-podman-over-docker-desktop-33368e031ba0

Comment: Thank you! this fixed issue `Error: statfs xxx no such file or directory` on my Mac. Now `podman-compose` runs successfully.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make sure to **mount volume first to podman machine** (in the `podman machine init` command).

Let’s say, we’re interested in:

- option to mount the $HOME directory (or any of it’s subdirectories) to containers,
- reserving 4 CPUs, 60GB of disk space and 6GB of memory for podman machine.

Let’s create the podman machine using:

```
podman machine init --cpus=4 --disk-size=60 --memory=6096 -v $HOME:$HOME
```

and start it afterwads:

```
podman machine start
```

To see if it runs, let’s use:

```
podman machine ls
```

Let’s first run sample (ubuntu) container without mount and see what is present in `/opt` dir:

```
podman run ubuntu ls /opt
```

No output indicates, that `/opt` dir is empty in the container.

Now let’s try with volume mount option:

```
mkdir test-dir
touch test-dir/test-file.txt
podman run -v ./test-dir:/opt ubuntu ls /opt
test-file.txt
```

We see that mounted dir with it’s content is accessible in container now!

(Content extracted from:
https://medium.com/@butkovic/favoring-podman-over-docker-desktop-33368e031ba0)

Answer (score 6):

If you have Windows and WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux), then it is possible to create a volume without having to remove and re-init podman-machine-default.

First connect to the podman machine using WSL:

```
wsl -d podman-machine-default
```

Then execute these commands:

```bash
[root@COMPUTER ~]# podman volume create myVolume
myVolume
[root@COMPUTER ~]# podman volume mount myVolume
/var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/myVolume/_data
```

Now to share files with a container, copy them from the WSL mount point into the volume mount point:

```bash
[root@COMPUTER ~]# cp /mnt/c/users/myname/myfolder/*.* /var/lib/containers/storage/volumes/myVolume/_data
```

Finally you can mount a volume in a container to access these files. Exit wsl and run:

```
podman run --rm -v myVolume:/remoteFolder -t docker.io/bash ls /remoteFolder
```

> Be careful, arguments ordering matters

Answer (score 3):

Iterating on [@zhigang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542236/179581)'s answer:

```
podman machine stop podman-machine-default || true
podman machine rm podman-machine-default --force || true
podman machine init -v "$(pwd):$(pwd)"
podman machine start
```

Now docker-compose / podman-compose just work with their config

```
version: '3.9'  # needed for PyCharm to work
services:
  app:
    image: python:alpine
    working_dir: /app/
    volumes: [.:/app/]
```

```
$ podman-compose run --rm app venv/bin/python main.py
```

Comment: from podman 4.1.1, -v $HOME:$HOME is automatically mounted by default `init` command

Answer (score 0):

Check if [podman 4.0.0](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v4.0.0) (and [latest releases](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/) like 4.0.2) from Feb. 2022 would help.

There are still bugs (like [issue 13548](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13548)), but the idea is:

Issue [10379 "Shared volumes, like in Kubernetes Pod"](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/10379) has been resolved with [PR 11409](https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/11409).

> ### Pod Volumes Support
>
> added support for the `--volume` flag in pods using the new infra container design.
> Users can specify all volume options they can with regular containers.
>
> Specifying the `--volume` flag causes the infra container to be populated with the specified mounts.
> All containers joining the pod then have a `VolumesFrom` container, causing them to inherit the mounts.

The [documentation](https://github.com/cdoern/podman/blob/84005330aa3d25cf6134fffc1bf20354d4a3dd85/docs/source/markdown/podman-pod-create.1.md#--volume--vsource-volumehost-dircontainer-diroptions) mentions:

> Create a bind mount.
>
> If you specify, `-v /HOST-DIR:/CONTAINER-DIR`, Podman bind mounts `/HOST-DIR` in the host to `/CONTAINER-DIR` in the Podman container.
>
> Similarly, `-v SOURCE-VOLUME:/CONTAINER-DIR` will mount the volume in the host to the container.
> If no such named volume exists, Podman will create one.

---

Note: issue 13548 has been resolved with [PR 13594](https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/13594) and [`cdoern/podman` commit 7a53428](https://github.com/cdoern/podman/commit/7a5342804944472246ed0b977e9088e0b01be87b) (Apr. 2022)

> ### fix pod volume passing and alter infra inheritance
>
> the infra `Inherit` function was not properly passing pod volume information to new containers.
>
> Alter the `inherit` function and struct to use the new `ConfigToSpec` function used in clone pick and choose the proper entities from a temp spec and validate them on the spegen side rather.
> than passing directly to a config

---

Pending all issues to be resolved, [Dmitry Kankalovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931559/dmitry-kankalovich) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298356/how-to-mount-a-volume-from-a-local-machine-on-podman/71497834#comment126926887_71497834):

> For now (Apr. 2022), I went with the workaround to mount the volume at the time of machine init: `podman machine init -v ./data:/mnt/data` which is not flexible at all, but gets wheels rolling.

Comment: I was hoping for it to work, but nope. I've updated podman to 4.0.2 and re-created the VM. Still the same error. Perhaps I should somehow enforce the latest qemu VM if thats the case

Comment: @DmitryKankalovich Maybe create a new issue, referencing https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/10379? Your use case needs to be investigated.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look at that. For now I went with the workaround to mount the volume at the time of machine init `podman machine init -v ./data:/mnt/data` which is not flexible at all, but gets wheels rolling

Comment: @DmitryKankalovich OK, thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer as well.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend using the `--mount` flag instead of `-v` or `--volume`.  I'm assuming you'd like to be able to easily modify the files on your host while running your app in a container.  Here's a quick example:

First, the directory needs to exist on the host:

```
user@host:~$ mkdir ~/localFolder
```

Create a file inside of the `~/localFolder` directory with some text inside:

```
user@host:~$ echo "Sample Text" > ~/localFolder/test
```

Then, start up your container using a bind mount.  This example is using a podman rootless container with a Debian Bullseye image as an unprivileged user.  Note: It is best practice to use an absolute path for both the source (host) and target (container) directories:

```
user@host:~$ podman run -it --rm --mount type=bind,source=/home/$USER/localFolder,target=/remoteFolder docker.io/debian:bullseye /bin/bash
```

Now your `~/localFolder` directory will be accessible inside of your container as `/remoteFolder`:

```
root@f724a0337f76:/# cat /remoteFolder/test 
Sample Text
```

You can add new files or modify existing files in this folder without restarting the container.

Docker has a great explanation of bind mounts here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still getting an error like `Error: statfs ~/localFolder: no such file or directory`

Comment: Are you getting that error in your container or on the host?

Comment: when podman is using a VM (for example on Mac), we need first to mount the host into the VM and then from the VM into the container. Sadly there are 3 layers involved here.

Comment: This error is in the container I think (the host has that file). So, how can I mount the host into the VM?

Comment: The error is from podman on the virtual machine, the container is never started. [this](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8016) is the feature request.

Comment: Agree with @Bracken, I still didn't find the `-v` work like docker on the podman side yet. Hope it would be implemented soon.