# Podman mount host volume return 'Error: statfs: no such file or directory' in Mac OS

Tags: mount, podman

Recently switched from Docker Desktop to Podman, everything work smoothly except when I want to mount host volume into container. e.g.

```
➜  ~ podman run --name nginx -v ~/bin/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro -d -p 8080:80 nginx
Error: statfs /Users/rb/bin/nginx/nginx.conf: no such file or directory

➜  ~  ls -lt ~/bin/nginx/nginx.conf                                                                 
-rw-r--r--  1 rb staff  490 Apr 23 14:31 /Users/rb/bin/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The host file `~/bin/nginx/nginx.conf` do exist, so what's the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/12123

Comment: So we should set the `-v` when init the podman. ? `podman machine init --cpus=1 --disk-size=2 --memory=2048 -v ~/bin/:/bin`

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/71542236/10644863

Answer (score 17):

Try the following:

1. Restart of VM:

   ```bash
   podman machine stop; podman machine start
   ```

   As [@rafagarci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9477227/rafagarci) mentioned in comments, sometimes new start failed and you should run these commands again a few times.

   Then mount (`-v`) works fine.
2. If restart doesn't help then try to recreate your [podman machine](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine.1.html):

   ```bash
   podman machine stop
   podman machine rm
   podman machine init # you may specify parameters for your VM
   podman machine start
   ```

   In [documentation](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-machine-init.1.html) you may find parameters for `podman machine init` command.

Comment: I had to stop and re-start podman multiple times until it successfully mounted my machine's directories.

Answer (score 11):

On podman 4.5.1 this should not be an issue anymore , the default Podman machine already mounts `/Users`, `/private` and `/var/folders` in macOS.

If you are getting `Error: statfs /Users/xxxxx/yyyy  : no such file or directory` it's probably a temporary error do

```
podman machine stop
podman machine start
Waiting for VM ...
Mounting volume... /Users:/Users
Mounting volume... /private:/private
Mounting volume... /var/folders:/var/folders
```

After that you should be able to mount anything under /Users

```
podman run -ti --rm -v "$HOME:/myhome" ubi8 
[root@ba2054e82401 /]# ls /myhome
```

Only do `podman machine rm` as a last resort, because that will delete your containers, and downloaded images, etc.

Comment: Guess what, with podman `4.7.1` the issue came back...  or to me more precise with fedora-core-39 podman machine as is the one that seems to be downloaded. Might be https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/20081 bug

Comment: thanks, I got the fsstat not found errors changing every time i ran podman, the "podman machine stop" and "start" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem on MacOs.

I fixed it when used mount point not from the host machine itself, but from podman virtual machine.

So firstly i mounted the host volume to podman vm:

```
podman machine init -v $HOST_VOLUME:/mnt/$PODMAN_VM_VOLUME
```

And after that mounted PODMAN_VM_VOLUME to CONTAINER_VOLUME:

```
podman run -d -it --name test -v /mnt/$PODMAN_VM_VOLUME:/$CONTAINER_VOLUME
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from mounting a volume at the podman machine init I had to additionally run:

```
podman machine set --rootful podman-machine-default
```

and then it worked for me for a yaml file with Compose.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was using Git Bash instead of Windows PowerShell, hope that helps anyone!

Comment: The question mention MacOS, I don't think PowerShell is the issue