# PODMAN Error: statfs no such file or directory

Tags: podman

I recently migrated to `podman` from `docker` because of licensing issues. `podman` build works seamlessly. However I am not able to run image on my local MAC (Intel chip).

I am running following command :

```
podman run -d -e "LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG" -it -v /Users/myuser/logs/:/logs
```

The same command used to run fine with docker but with podman it gives error:

> Error: statfs /Users/myuser/logs: no such file or directory

This directory is there on my MAC with `777` permissions but still podman is giving error.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298356/how-to-mount-a-volume-from-a-local-machine-on-podman) and [this](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8302) article which suggests to use `-v` option to mount volumes during init but when I do the same I get the error:

Command:

```
podman machine init --cpus=4 --disk-size=60 --memory=6096 -v $HOME:$HOME
```

Error:

> Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'v' in -v

Podman version I am using (ran `brew upgrade podman` today i.e. 29Nov2022)::

> Client: Version:      3.4.2 API Version:  3.4.2 Go Version:   go1.17.2
> Built:        Fri Nov 12 21:38:25 2021 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
>
> Server: Version:      4.3.0 API Version:  4.3.0 Go Version:   go1.19.2
> Built:        Fri Oct 21 13:39:51 2022 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: Did you got any answer to this , even i face the same issue

Comment: @IrfanPathan Unfortunately no. Had to migrate to rancher.